# Unable to display images from Firebase(using glide)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

Before adding material design it was working, but after changing my layout(Nothing changed about imageview) I am unable show images.

```
public class DownloadFile extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download_file);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Wait for the action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                yukle();
            }
        });


    }

    public void yukle(){
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
        StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/pic.jpg");

        imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        Glide.with(this)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(riversRef)
                .into(imageview);
    }
}
```

I am getting the error below

```
03-24 07:41:22.284 22900-22900/com.furkan.profil E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.furkan.profil, PID: 22900
                                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View
                                                                   at com.bumptech.glide.GenericRequestBuilder.into(GenericRequestBuilder.java:678)
                                                                   at com.bumptech.glide.DrawableRequestBuilder.into(DrawableRequestBuilder.java:448)
                                                                   at com.furkan.profil.DownloadFile.yukle(DownloadFile.java:58)
                                                                   at com.furkan.profil.DownloadFile$1.onClick(DownloadFile.java:40)
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
03-24 07:41:30.213 22900-22994/com.furkan.profil W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

At Firebase side here is my rules

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
       allow read: if true;
       allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as your stacktrace indicates the imageview you are passing in Glide is null. So the id that you set as a parameter in `findViewById` must be wrong. Ensure that you pass the correct id, otherwise post your xml so we have more info.

Comment: Thanks I solved the problem. Problem was my imageView doesn't have any id. And I gave him the ID and the problem solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

put this line on your onCreate

```
imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```